# Can I build my own sandbox environment with Golang/Python?

Tags: sandbox

Can I build my own sandbox environment with Golang/Python?
I want to build containerized sandbox environment that can run dedicated programs (i.e. .exe, .msi)

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Do you have any specific question about this?

Comment: Is there any frameworks/libraries to build sandbox environment with them? I can't find none of them.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing. Also, searching for frameworks or libraries is off-topic on SO